# Simple PHP CMS with internationalization, static website, and blog capabilities?

Tags: php, content-management-system

I would like to know if there's a PHP CMS which makes things like editing a block of text easy.

It also should let the user separtare content in columns.

I'm using Wordpress right now, but it seems like the only way of letting the user add content is in form of posts.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [MojoMotor](http://mojomotor.com/) it's different from the standard CMS packages and is based off CodeIgniter.

Comment: I will check it out I use to love CodeIgniter

Comment: Interesting I've never heard of this! Looks like something to keep an eye on.

Answer (score 1):

Joomla is the Answer. It has all the properties you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress allows adding pages too. These live outside the blog and are not automatically shown in the blog index.

If you decide to drop WordPress after all, you could take a look at [9 alternatives to WordPress](http://www.mitchelaneous.com/2007/09/19/9-wordpress-alternatives/).

Comment: I know I can add pages. But I would like to know a CMS which makes things like building columns and blocks easy.

Comment: In that case you should pick Joomla or any of the other suggestions I linked to. Joomla has a quite rich feature set where you can select a theme and visually show or hide parts pf them. But you are still depending on themes made by others, unless you have the knowledge to develop these yourself.